# Pandas: how to select dataframe rows with a Series of values that must be matched?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a selector `Series`, that is a `Series` treated as a query of a `DataFrame` in that the selector `Series`'s index is a subset of the rows of a `DataFrame` to be queried, and whose values are to be matched in the query, currently, I'm doing the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':11,'b':22,'c':33}, {'a':1,'b':22,'c':333}])
selector_series = pd.Series({'a':1,'b':22})
desired_df = df[pd.DataFrame([df[x]==selector_series[x] for x in selector_series.index.intersection(df.columns)]).all()]
print(desired_df)
```

Output:

```
   a   b    c
2  1  22  333
```

However, I suspect this kind of thing is a common enough operation that there is a more "Pandasic" (as opposed to Pythonic) way of doing the same thing.  Is there?

Comment: Can you define everything undefined in the current code snippet? `df`, `selector_series`, and `selector`

Comment: selector Series's index is a subset of the "column labels" (not "rows") of a DataFrame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas comparison methods like [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) perform an alignment operation. This is typically used to align for "outer" comparison:

Take this modified example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 11, 1], 'b': [2, 22, 22], 'c': [3, 33, 333]})
selector_series = pd.Series({'a': 1, 'b': 22, 'd': 156})
```

```
df.eq(selector_series)
       a      b      c      d
0   True  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False
2   True   True  False  False
```

Notice how the *union* of columns between the Series and the DataFrame are compared. In this case, however, we do not want this since `c` (only being in the DataFrame) and `d` (only being in the Series) can only ever be `False`.

---

We can instead, explicitly [`align`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.align.html) to override the default `how` with `'inner'`.

Here is a helper method:

```
def intersection_eq(df_: pd.DataFrame, s_: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    aligned_df_, aligned_s_ = df_.align(s_, join='inner', axis=1, copy=False)
    return aligned_df_.eq(aligned_s_)
```

Now this operation returns only the *common* columns in both or the *intersection*.

```
intersection_eq(df, selector_series)

       a      b
0   True  False
1  False   True
2   True   True
```

Now we can filter as typical with [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) on `axis=1`:

```
df[intersection_eq(df, selector_series).all(axis=1)]

   a   b    c
2  1  22  333
```

---

Naturally, we could also add this to our DataFrame definition, or create a SubClass of DataFrame to allow for more natural syntax:

```
def intersection_eq(df_: pd.DataFrame, s_: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    aligned_df_, aligned_s_ = df_.align(s_, join='inner', axis=1, copy=False)
    return aligned_df_.eq(aligned_s_)


pd.DataFrame.intersection_eq = intersection_eq
```

Which allows for usage like:

```
df[df.intersection_eq(selector_series).all(axis=1)]

   a   b    c
2  1  22  333
```

Comment: Since (as I inferred from the timestamps) you wrote this answer after mozway's I presume you had reason to believe it superior even though it is more verbose.  In what way is it superior?

Comment: I don't understand your presumption. StackOverflow looks to be a repository of questions and answers. This answer describes general alignment for pandas structures which is generally helpful and I hoped that it would draw attention to a relatively underused operation. Furthermore, as outlined above, the `align` function is specifically the operation the pandas library _itself_ uses. As such, it is frequently optimized as many operations need to do an alignment check before processing.

Comment: In terms of those optimizations, `copy=False`, is a great example. If alignment does not need to occur it returns a reference to the element instead of making an identical copy. Meaning that if we're talking about the example in the OP, subsetting both structures with an index results in a copy of the DataFrame (not containing `c`) and a copy of the Series (an exact copy no change). `align`, however, will produces a copy of the DataFrame (not containing `c`) but a _reference_ to the original Series (no copy made). Making align both more space and more time efficient in that case.

Comment: I think I understand now:  You are proposing a two layered solution for what seems to me to be a good reason:  There is a potentially useful abstraction "intersection_eq" that, if defined as an extension to the DataFrame class, will find general utility to reduce verbosity, but to implement it optimally requires what I called "verbosity" in its definition.

Answer (score 1):

A more natural approach for pandas would be not to use loops but rather the [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) method for comparison on the common indices:

```
idx = df.columns.intersection(selector_series.index)
df.loc[df[idx].eq(selector_series.loc[idx]).all(1)]
```

Comment: I agree except that you should probably subset _before_ eq so that you can do less comparisons over all, because currently you're doing a bunch of unneeded equality checks then throwing them away. `df[df[df.columns.intersection(selector_series.index)].eq(selector_series).all(1)]`

Comment: @HenryEcker that's only partially true, if you do that you'll always get False if there are extra indices in the series, so you need to subselect both if doing it beforehand. I updated the answer ;)

Comment: If we know beforehand that Series index is a subset of DataFrame column labels, as Question's Author assumes, then `selector_series` is sufficient instead of `selector_series.loc[idx]`. (Otherwise, if it wasn't necessarily a subset, we'd have to decide what output we want in case of partial subset matching, but solution would differ and also e.g. `selector_series` (`df.loc[df[idx].eq(selector_series).all(1)]`) would have to be used so that in case of `pd.Series({'x':1,'y':22})` we'd get an empty (not full) dataframe.)